# Finding the minimum value of the function $f(x,y,z) = xy+xz+yz-2xyz $ in a specific set

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to prove that for every $c < 3$ the function:

$$ f(x,y,z) = xy+xz+yz-2xyz $$

does not have a minimum value in the set:

$$S = \big\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x > 0, y>0, z>0, x+y+z=c\big\}$$

**I'm stuck with my following best attempt:**

I took the compact set:
$$K = \big\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0, x+y+z=c\big\}$$

with the goal of separating between the boundary and $int(K)$, showing that any critical point in $int(K)$ has value $\epsilon>0$ (and then, claiming that since boundary points like $(0,0,c)$ get value $0$, then by continuity we can always get a smaller value than $\epsilon$  by approaching the boundary).

To accomplish this, I defined another function:

$$ \phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$$
$$ \phi(x,y) \to (x,y,c-x-y)$$

and tried to compute the critical points of $f\circ \phi$ to find candidates for such internal points in $K$, but this leads to quadratic equations in $x,y$, at which point I cannot see how to proceed. Specifically, I got:

$$\nabla f (x,y) =(2y^2+4xy-2yc-y-2x+c, 2x^2+4xy-2xc-x-2y+c)$$

so equating $\nabla f(x,y)=0$ and subtracting the second from the first yields:

$$ (y-x)(2(y+x)-2c+1)=0$$

so that $y=x$ or $2(y+x)-2c+1=0$.

But -- if I try to plug $y=x$ into the second equation resulting from $\nabla f(x,y)=0$, for example, I get a quadratic equation which seems to lead me nowhere. I even tried just bounding the value of $f\circ \phi$ in $K$, but to no avail.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

I believe I got it (just needed to do some algebra after plugging in, e.g. $x=y$).
Thanks anyway, will close the question.

Comment: You have a great idea. Can you directly show that $f(x,y,z) > 0 $, and that greatest lower bound is not achieved?

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried that, but was unsuccessful. What *is* working (so far) is plugging back in the option of $y=x$ (hopefully the second option one will work as smoothly too), and turning into an argument of the form $(1-2y)(-3y+c)=$ which is easier to handle now....
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(OP claims they were able to fix their proof. Here's the quick approach I mentioned in the comment.)

**Claim:** If $ 0 < c < 3$, then $f(x,y, z) > 0$.

**Proof:** $1 > \frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{xyz} \Rightarrow 1 > xyz$.
Also, $ xyz > 0 $ from the condition, hence $ 1 > xyz > 0 $.
$f(x,y,z) = xy+yz+zx - 2xyz\geq 3\sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}  - 2xyz$.
Setting $\sqrt[3]{xyz} = a$, observe that $ 3a^2 - 2a^3 > 0$ on the domain $ 0 < a < 1$.

**Claim:** For fixed $ 0 < c < 3$, $0$ is the greatest lower bound of $f(x, y, z)$, and is not achieved.

**Proof:** Show that  $ f( \epsilon, \epsilon, c - 2\epsilon) \rightarrow 0 $.
That 0 is not achieved is shown by the previous claim.

Comment: Clean approach - thanks. But how did you get the inequality in $f$? ($\geq3...$)?

Comment: @Anon What do you mean by "in $f$"? $\quad$ Note that I had a minor typo. I'm using AMGM to conclude that $xy +yz + zx \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{x^2y^2z^2}$.